# onbeforeunload doesn't catch all events

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I have a problem with on onbeforeunload event

this is the part of code to manage event

```
myWindow = window.open("configuration?id="+id);
myWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
    window.location.href = "service?id="+id;
};
```

`configuration` is a page witch has a lot of interaction (GET or POST calls) with server.

unload event function (`window.location.href = "service?id="+id`) is a page refresh after a closure of a configuration page.

my problem is:
when configuration page does first GET call to server, there is a refresh on service. but after that, when cofiguration does another GET call, service doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure you can change the window.location.href in a onbeforeunload event.

Comment: ...but first time that code works...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd either need to include that `onbeforeunload` event handler in the actual code of that page displayed in the popup window or handle the second unload event like this:

```
myWindow = window.open("configuration?id="+id);
myWindow.onload = function() {
    myWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
        window.location.href = "service?id="+id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, did not test it, it's just an idea to put you towards the right direction...

Comment: ok, onLoad have to be lowercase, with onload your code works like my code: only fist time...